# How do I get position of QSlider bar in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qslider, qabstractslider

I'm using QSlider object in my Qt application and I want to get the position of the slider bar upon moving it. I tried using `pos()` function, but it always returns `QPoint()` with the same values of *x* and *y* (i suppose it returns position of top left corner of slider):

```
ui->horizontalSlider->pos();
```

Then I tried dividing the slider width by 100 and adding that value multiplicated by slider `value()` to most-left position:

```
SliderStep = ui->horizontalSlider->width()/100;

(ui->horizontalSlider->value()) * SliderStep + ui->horisontalSlider->geometry().x();
```

It kind of works for me, but values are not very accurate since SliderStep has to be *double* and coordinates are *integer* values. I always noticed that I can get slider values by either using `value()` or `sliderPosition()` functions since they always return the same value for me:

```
qDebug()<<ui->horizontalSlider->sliderPosition();
qDebug()<<ui->horizontalSlider->value();
```

So my question is, is there a more convinient or "right" way to get coordinates of a slider bar? What's the difference between those two functions? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QSlider mouse direct jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132597/qslider-mouse-direct-jump)

Comment: regarding value/sliderPosition: [QAbstractSlider::tracking](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#tracking-prop)

Comment: What about `QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue()` function?

Comment: If tracking is enabled (the default), sliderPosition()  is identical to value().